# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences) while getting FCM in background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, sharedpreferences

I'm working on a Flutter app in which I'm using the shared_preferences: ^2.0.13 package.

- Flutter version : 2.10.1 (latest)
- gradle version: 6.7
- Android gradle plugin version: 4.1.3
- kotlin version: 1.6.10
- flutterEmbedding 2 (in android menifiest)

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences).

While getting FCM message received in background.

main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('Got a message onBackgroundMessageHandler_');
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

  print('Shared pref process starts');
  SharedPreferences sf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sf.setString("key", "Value");
  print('${sf.getKeys()}');
  print('Shared pref process ends');
}

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

}
```

Comment: Something that work for me is: Delete your pubspec.lock, and press Pub Get in your pubspec.yaml, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.

Comment: @Amol Mishra It doesn't work for me.

Comment: you try this command `Flutter clean`

Comment: @Amol Mishra i have tried flutter clean also its not working for me.

Comment: try uninstalling the app and reinstalling it

Comment: @Pokaboom i have already try this many times. but not working getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

please reference to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623763/flutter-using-path-provider-when-app-is-in-background/62771536#62771536)

you need to register share_preference for background access

```
io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
```

Comment: I have already done in my application.kt but its not working for me.

Comment: In the latest versions of flutter plugins are automatically registered by generated_plugin_registrant.dart, in this case FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage uses seperate isolate than main and in this isolate all third party dependencies gets unavailable.

Comment: @MerdaDev, How can we fix this then?

Answer (score 1):

Some edit into your code below:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences_android/shared_preferences_android.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences_ios/shared_preferences_ios.dart';

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('Got a message onBackgroundMessageHandler_');
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

  print('Shared pref process starts');
  // I am not sure what does SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith(); but it can solve problem
  if (Platform.isAndroid) SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
  if (Platform.isIOS) SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
  SharedPreferences sf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sf.setString("key", "Value");
  print('${sf.getKeys()}');
  print('Shared pref process ends');
}

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

There wasn't a little bit of information about it, espacially in firebase cloud messaging docs. I think this information must be available in onBackgroundMessage section of docs!